# How do I specify the computer configuration before the download

Tags: kernel

I am using a 64 bit PC to do the download. I want to install Ubuntu on an older PC that currently doesn't work at all - with (obviously) no internet access of its own. When I download Ubuntu and put the image on a CD and use it to boot the older PC I get told that the kernel is for a 64 bit PC and this one is i686 (or something) and go get the right kernel. But I didn't get the option to choose the right kernel and can't see how to get it. Where do I look for a place to specify what sort of download I want please?

Comment: You could try Lubuntu, it supports 32 bit and works well on older systems

Answer (score 1):

All Ubuntu ISO images are available from [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) and its [mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+cdmirrors).

Currently supported Ubuntu releases are 14.04, 16.04, and 17.10. If you want to install 17.10, you cannot use the standard "Desktop" Live CD image, as such images are no longer made for 32-bit (i386) machines. Instead, you must use the "Server" image, with a text-based installer, and install a desktop manually. Alternatively, you can install 16.04 from its i386 "Desktop" image, and upgrade to 18.04 when it is released in April.

Comment: Thank you, I installed 16.04 and it seems to work fine. Appreciate the quick assistance.

Answer (score 0):

32-bit Ubuntu can be downloaded from [Ubuntu Alternative downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads)

Comment: Note that there isn't one for 17.10 32-bit. fkraiem's answer covers this.

Comment: @ WJAndrea Good catch! Now i'm wondering why it is not listed there. EOL 7/18? A side note - **17.10.1** is not on [Wiki either](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: It's not listed because it doesn't exist. Canonical has stopped building 32-bit desktop images for Ubuntu. See [this article](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/09/ubuntu-17-10-32-bit-builds-dropped)